# Процедуры в ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

Реализую проект на `ASP.NET`, в котором ожидаемое количество пользователей будет не очень большим, но количество запросов будет гораздо больше!

Нужен совет, как лучше сделать: обращаться к хранимым процедурам по имени через `MySQLCommand()` или писать обычные строковые запросы?
Будет ли какой-то заметный выигрыш в производительности, если использовать процедуры?

Comment: Хранимые процедуры дадут небольшой выигрыш в скорости. Они ведь уже хранятся скомпилированными, в то время как "обычный строковый запрос" сервер SQL будет каждый раз разбирать и компилить, прежде чем выполнить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хранимые процедуры лучше и вот почему

- Код не перемешан с SQL, есть четкое разделение логики БД и логики приложения
- Viusal Studio имеет специальный тип проектов для бд, где удобно хранить все вьюшки и процедуры, что упрощает развертывание
- Процедуры в 99% случаев лучше оптимизируются сервером

И на мой взгляд, у просто запросов есть только 1 сценарий использования прямо из кода, это когда запрос содержит максимум 1-2 таблицы и несложное условие, что можно записать в одну строковую строчку. Всё остальное красивее вынести в процедуру.

Answer (score 2):

ХП хороши, когда они на себе несут какуето логику, а не просто выполняют запрос...